# Subtract two prices

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, subquery

I want to subtract two prices in SQL Server. Both prices are in the same table, for example list_id 5 - list_id6 I want to get results.

```
SELECT MIN(fiyat) - MAX(fiyat) 
FROM table  
WHERE liste_id in (5,6)
```

I want to subtract list_id 6 from list_id 5 here.

Comment: What is the data-type of `fiyat` (is it `money`, `int`, `bigint`, `decimal`, etc)? And is it `NULL` or `NOT NULL`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer
int data type

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to substract the price of `liste_id` `5` from the price of `liste_id` `6`.

One option uses two subqueries:

```
select
    (select fiyat from mytable where list_id = 5)
    - (select fiyat from mytable where list_id = 6) as res
```

You can also use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when liste_id = 5 then fiyat end) - max(case when liste_id = 6 then fiyat end)
from mytable
where liste_id in (5, 6)
```

Note that this assumes that `liste_id` is a unique key in the table, in other words there is at most one row for a given value.

Comment: thank you very much. My problem was solved in an incredibly short time thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

SQL is concerned with set-operations, not arithmetic. So if you have two rows that you want to get a single scalar value from then use you should use separate T-SQL variables, like so:

```
DECLARE @fiyat_5 int = ( SELECT fiyat FROM [table] WHERE liste_id = 5 );
DECLARE @fiyat_6 int = ( SELECT fiyat FROM [table] WHERE liste_id = 6 );

IF @fiyat_5 IS NULL OR @fiyat_6 IS NULL
BEGIN
    THROW 51000, 'Either value does not exist.', 1;  
END;

SELECT ( @fiyat_5 - @fiyat_6 ) AS diff;
```

Comment: thank you very much. My problem was solved in an incredibly short time thanks to you